# print n lines, then skip n lines in large text file

Tags: bash, sed

I want to use sed to print n lines, skip n lines, print n lines etc until the end of a text file, starting at a certain line. eg stating at line 4, print 5-9, the skip 10-14, print 15-19 etc
From the file

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I want

```
5
6
7
8
9
15
16
17
18
19
25
26
27
28
29
35
36
37
38
39
etc
```

If I try

```
sed -n '4~5p' FILE.txt > NEWFILE.txt
```

will give me
4
9
14
19

which I don't want.

Comment: This seems better suited to `awk`.

Comment: Do you bother to read the tag descriptions? **n is a CLI for managing multiple Node.js / io.js versions.** What does that have to do with `sed`?

Comment: When I try your command I get `4, 9, 14, 20`, not the same lines you show.

Comment: Did you mean to skip `18` in your sample input? If so then explain why, if not then fix it.

Comment: If your problem is solved now, please mark one of the answer as accepted, so that this question no longes comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: Hi  Bamar, I do try to read the tag description but I no idea what CLI, Node.js / io.js is, so It's quite hard recoqnise these as solution. I asked for a sed solution because I'm familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, I actually entered the wrong numbers(my linux environment is partitioned from the internet at my work). I did also get 4,9,14,20.

Comment: Thanks, Ed Morton. Fixed now.  Apologies, all.  This is my first try at consulting the stackoverflow oracle and it seems that I'm a bit loose. Apologies for time wasted.

Comment: Now you've got lines in your expected output that don't appear in your input and no explanation for how they got there. It's very simple - post sample input which, when the tool you want is run against it, will produce the post expected output. Don't post partial output and certainly don't post output that can't be produced from your input.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this in `sed`, as it can't do arithmetic. `awk` is better:

```
awk 'NR%10 >= 5' FILE.txt > NEWFILE.txt
```

`NR%10` is the record number modulo 10 (i.e. the last digit of the line number). So this prints any line where the last digit of the line number is at least 5: 5-9, 15-19, 25-29, etc.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. This will skip 10-14 so it works as promised, but I'm also trying to skip 20-24, 30-34 etc...

Comment: That's what it does. `NR % 10` is the last digit of the line number. So it only prints lines where the last digit is 5 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '!(NR%5){f=!f} f' file
5
6
7
8
9
15
16
17
18
19
```

Comment: Not strictly true, but agree that Awk is a more natural tool for this particular task, and many others.

Comment: I've been using sed for 30+ years and continue to use it almost every day and I know it's hard to believe but when you actually try to come up with other applications where a sed solution is "better" than an equivalent awk one, I don't think those cases exist as the sed solution is always harder to understand and modify if/when there's small requirements changes and sed solutions change drastically wrt language constructs given just slightly different requirements. See http://awk.info/?doc/tip/sedInAwk.html for some examples of sed/awk equivalent code.

Comment: Well, sed can use back references in matches, allowing it to match a subset of non-regular context-free languages that awk cannot easily handle. If you need that, awk is generally not an option while sed might be (although at that point you may want to consider using perl). I agree that most of the time complicated sed (i.e., anything that goes beyond a series of `s///` statements) is something you want to use for fun puzzles more than production, though.

Comment: I understand and I'm sure there can be some impact on brevity of being able to use them but in 30+ years of UNIX scripting I've never used backreferences on the LHS and I don't recall ever wishing for it so there must always have been a simple alternative in sed or awk for the cases I've had to handle where I could have used them (perl isn't available on many of the machines I work on). YMMV I suppose but I can't imagine the benefits of LHS backreferences being worth dealing with the rest of a complicated sed script.

Comment: Then you typed the script instead of copy/pasting it and made a mistake doing so. Oh hang on, maybe your shell attaches some specific meaning to `!` - if so, read your shell man page (and/or see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3748/133219) and disable that or store the script in a file and execute it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sed solution. Try figuring that out ;)

```
sed -n 'n ; n ; n ; n ; n ; h ; n ; H ; n ; H ; n ; H ; n ; H ; x ; p' file
```

Comment: Thanks henrikgiesel.This actually works perfectly for this example but I fear that it may become a little unwieldly if I want to skip 500 lines of text so I'm going to keep hunting...

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '5~10,+4p' file
```

Use a range where the first address steps ever 10 lines from line 5 and the second address is 4 lines following the first address.
See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) for details.

BTW `sed -n '4~5p'` does not give the answer you thought.

Comment: Thanks potong. This will skip 10-14, but I'm also trying to skip 20-24, 30-34 etc...<br/> I've added the wrong text for my output for sed -n '4~5p' - fixed now

Comment: @StanzaAlley this solution does that.